# Defining onchange methods in odoo if on_change is defined on the model

Tags: odoo, onchange

I'm trying to define an `onchange` event on the field `amount` and `line_cr_ids.amount` on `account.voucher` but any definition like this:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('line_cr_ids', 'line_cr_ids.amount')
def _line_amount_onchange(self):
    ...
```

Or

```
@api.one
@api.onchange('amount')                                 
def _onchange_amount(self):
    ...
```

Are never called, I noticed that a `on_change` parameter is defined on those fields in the view. Does it means the only way to get the `onchange` is to redefine the one already defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to redefine the on_change method called by the view.
Or change the view itself removing it as attribute.

Comment: I found a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I solved my problem as I didn't want to remove the `on_change` attributes... There is a better and more stable way of working than using the `api.onchange` decorator for now. I guess the decorators could get more stable over time but in my case it didn't fit at all. It would get called and sometimes it wouldn't... Children of object do not have access to parent object because the ORM doesn't allow it... ask me why I don't know...

That said the holy grail is to override the `onchange` method on the object.

I noticed that whenever something happens, it would call the `onchange` method on my `account.voucher` object.

So the solution is to create a method:

```
class AccountVoucher(models.Model):
    ...
    @api.model
    def onchange(self, ids, values, field, fields):
        result = super(AccountVoucher, self).onchange(
            values, field, fields
        )
        #...
        # do whatever you want here change result and return it
        #...
        result
```

This way, all changes are visible and it never miss. It also call other onchange when calling super so you don't miss anything. If you need to use decorators anyway, it shouldn't stop anything from working. In other words... while overriding `onchange`, you're getting at the root of the problem and nothing stops you from getting things done.